# How to generate guaranteed unique id for files stored on server?

Tags: amazon-s3, server, uniqueidentifier

I am a complete newbie in server side programming. Currently I am writing a service to store users files sent from ios app. I would like to generate a unique id for each file and also use it as file name. Problem is, many of the solutions, such as using a hash function, I found online have the risk of collision. So what is preferred way of doing that? I know AWS s3 generate a unique id fora each file. How did they implement this?

Comment: *"I know AWS s3 generate a unique id for each file."*  No, it doesn't.  For versioned buckets, each *version* an object will have a generated unique opaque string as a version identifier, but there is no documented reason to believe that these are constrained to uniqueness across different objects or different buckets or different regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever programming language you use probably has a GUID (sometimes called UUID) library which can be considered universally unique.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Hashing will not solve this problem at all, because the point of a hash is that two identical inputs should result in two identical outputs.  Therefor if two users upload `ThisIsAFile.pdf` both will has to say `a89na3` and there will be a collision.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing I am curious, if I use a number of servers to generated UUID for the users, each maybe a different implementation, lets say one is by GO, and another is by Javascript, would the probability of collision be higher? or it remains the same?

Comment: @craboz the whole point of UUID is that they are meant to be globally unique, regardless of who implemented them or how many servers they run on.  Let the implementors worry about that, and move on to making your awesome app!

Comment: A Type 1 UUID, properly implemented, has almost no possibility of a collision across multiple systems because its values are based primarily on a system identifier and on the current date/time with sub-microsecond resolution.  But, these are also much more easily predicted (if I know a recent ID you generated, it's much easier for me to potentially guess other recent past or future IDs) so this is a factor to take into consideration if guessability poses an issue (and if it does, that's often a sign that you're implementing security-through-obscurity, which is not a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to generate some wide *random* id. If you generate some random name of several dozen of characters like `_5E960vkoXF8_6t2yfMbEM0A_6uBsy060PxH_2YKKKmZkTR6` the collision probability can be made small enough to be negligible (e.g. your system would need to run many billions years to observe a single collision). If you want to estimate that probability, use the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) approach.

<sup>(collisions are not always an issue, if you can make their probability tiny enough)</sup>

[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s are exploiting this idea. So the simplest way is simply to use a library function generating them, e.g. [uuid_generate](https://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_generate). You may want to do likewise (that is code your own random id generator), but you need to be careful about randomness.

At least, you could use a *good* [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (such as a [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) one) that you would seed periodically (and at startup) with some random noise, e.g. using `/dev/random` (read *carefully* [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)...) or [getrandom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html). Or you could  buy some random generating hardware source (like [OneRNG](http://onerng.info/)).

BTW, if you suppose that the user's files contents do not change (so each file is written once at creation time), you could use some [cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) function on them (like [SHA 256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)). Then if two distinct users would upload exactly the *same* content (for example, the text of [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html)) you would store it *once* on your disk (in some *shared* file). The 
https://www.softwareheritage.org/ project is using such a technique.

<sup>(for cardinality reasons, collisions remain theoretically possible, but highly improbable)</sup>

You don't want to make [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) mathematically impossible. You probably do want to have them very improbable: if the probability is less than 10<sup>-50</sup> (or just 10<sup>-30</sup> that is about 2<sup>-100</sup>) you probably should not care (since our Earth planet will vanish before that collision is likely to happen).

Comment: This is the basic idea behind UUID/GUID's (I know you probably wrote this before my seeing my answer).  However, building your own is not advised because there are potential gotcha's with many random generators... and the existing libraries tend to be trivial to work with.

Comment: (yes, I did know about UUIDs)

Comment: Better but you're still going down a rabbit-hole.  There's a very simple tool that most languages have in their core libraries that just works.  Instead, you're mentioning system specific implementations that require thorough research, peer review and generally a lot of headache.  If you desperately need to create your own use a provided cryptographic RNG, make sure you consider the birthday problem, and cross your fingers.  Even then we're talking seconds vs hours of work.

Comment: I agree. In some cases, UUID are not appropriate.

Comment: But it is not several hours of work, only half an hour for me. Of course, one need to know something about UUIDs first (at least the principles).

Comment: You can always generate random, arbitrarily-wide strings before you need them, and store them in a database... then when you need one, lock the row and claim the id.  Or generate them as needed and try to insert into a database table with a unique constraint.  If the insert works, there's no collision, but if you get a duplicate key error, then repeat the process until you get a random value that has never been used.